# How can I use Data Explorer to search for posts containing an email address?

Tags: support, data-explorer

[Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) has a problem with a particular recurring kind of spam, all of which contain email addresses ([a deleted example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/45798/revisions), 10k / mod only).

I'm interested in querying Data Explorer to see what percentage of our *undeleted* answers actually contain email addresses. I'm not experienced with T-SQL, though, so I'm not sure how I'd go about this in a regular T-SQL environment. Apparently I can't use a query like this:

```
select [OwnerUserId], [Post Link], Body
from Posts
where contains(Body, '@')
```

... because I get this error on running it:

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'Posts' because it is not full-text indexed.

So what can I do to find posts containing an email address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data.SE's SQL engine doesn't allow for particularly complex expressions, but you can narrow this down to a reasonable set of posts by using dumb ol' [LIKE patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) if you, heh, like:

```
select OwnerUserId [User Link], Id [Post Link], Body
from Posts
where Body like '%[^ >]@[^ <]%'
```

[Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/query/216703)

Comment: Oh, that's how I'm meant to use those tags! I'll give this a spin when I'm back at my PC.